# How to apply App.vue extension in IntelliJ

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ.
I want to App.vue file to apply to Vue template.
Why don't be applied only App.vue? Help me please.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzwcX.jpg)